# Mysql.h c++ too many arguments

Tags: c++, mysql, linux

Now when I compile I recieve:

```
/usr/include/mysql/mysql.h:452: error: too many arguments to function int mysql_query(MYSQL*, const char*)
```

Is there a limit to the arguments for `mysql.h` and if so how do I get around it?

```
#include    <mysql/mysql.h>


string unknown = "Unknown";

MYSQL *conn;

conn = mysql_init(NULL);
mysql_real_connect(conn, "localhost", "root", "password", "alert", 0, NULL, 0);

mysql_query(conn, "INSERT INTO alert_tbl (alert_srcip, alert_country, alert_destip, alert_desthost, alert_destport, alert_bl) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')", src_ip,country_code,dest_ip,unknown,dest_prt,blip);

mysql_close(conn);
```

---

```
g++ test.c -o test -lstdc++ -I/usr/include/mysql -L/usr/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient
```

Comment: May I suggest reading the API documentation before asking... mysql_query() only allows 2 arguments, and you're passing a ton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-cpp-examples-prepared-statements.html

Answer (score 5):

You have to use [mysql_stmt_prepare](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-stmt-prepare.html) and then bind the parameter values one by one using the [mysql_stmt_bind_param](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-stmt-bind-param.html)

When the statement is ready, execute it with the [mysql_stmt_execute](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-stmt-execute.html)

Or use sprintf():

```
char query[1024 /* or longer */];

sprintf(query,
     "INSERT INTO alert_tbl"
     "(alert_srcip, alert_country, alert_destip, alert_desthost, alert_destport, "
     "alert_bl) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')",
     src_ip,country_code,dest_ip,unknown,dest_prt,blip);

mysql_query(conn, query);
```

Comment: Am I safe from sql injection with sprintf?  I looked at prepared/parameterized statements but it appears as if you have to write an entire page of code just to do an insert that way.

Comment: There a libraries like libodbc++ and even the language extensions from Sybase (SQL++ or something like that) to avoid typing "the entire page of code". Yes, the sprintf() is not a safe way and yes C++ is not the language for quick (in terms of development effort) SQL access.

Comment: Not that I am trying to avoid having to do some coding, I am just trying to learn c++ and when going the route of prepared statements it's difficult to see an example and understand enough to manipulate with what I am wanting to do without a better understanding.

Comment: You're on the right track then. C++ allows using multiple (variable) arguments using the '...' notation, but the MySQL's API is not the case. That's why you're getting the syntax errors. You have two opportunities: either form the query string using the std::stringstream/sprintf() or use the full-blown prepare/execute/fetch function set.

Comment: I am going to go for it, use prepared statements.  I am just thinking in my head how many lines of code that is going to be for 6 values.  At least when I am done I will have a pretty good grasp on what's going on.

Comment: If you're learning C++, try writing your own generic Query class with Bind() method inside. Then binding 6 params will take at most 6 lines of code. You can even declare the '<<' operator with safe buffer checking to your query class. But that's not the original question already.

Comment: Thanks alot Viktor. If I can get one written then I can just "take it with me where ever I go" and pull it out when needed.  I could really see this being beneficial putting in the time up front to save me time in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Or simply use:

```
char query[1000];
snprintf(query, 1000, "INSERT INTO alert_tbl (alert_srcip, alert_country, alert_destip, alert_desthost, alert_destport, alert_bl) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')", src_ip, country_code, dest_ip, unknown, dest_prt, blip);
mysql_query(conn, query);
```

Comment: I would clarify that in the answer

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using it, you are really passing many arguments to `mysql_query(..)`.

Use std::stringstream to build your query. (**Warning**: You need to ensure they are properly escaped).

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss<<"INSERT INTO alert_tbl (alert_srcip, alert_country, alert_destip, alert_desthost, alert_destport, alert_bl) VALUES ('"<<src_ip<<"','"<<country_code //and so on..

mysql_query(conn, ss.str().c_str());
```